# "To ask someone on a date" or "to ask someone out on a date"?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "ask someone on a date" and "ask someone out on a date"?

Comment: There is no practical difference. Perhaps having 'out' in the sentence implies that the date will occur at a event/restaurant as opposed to a date at a residence, but really, either sentence can be used interchangeably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am still not sure about "ask someone out {for/to} {a/zero article} something"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155909/i-am-still-not-sure-about-ask-someone-out-for-to-a-zero-article-something)

Answer (score 0):

To ask someone out would be the common phrasing. I would also use "for" rather than "on". "To ask someone out for a date." But also "to ask someone out" would commonly be inferred to be for a date in any case since I can't think of any examples where it's used for other things. There is "to call someone out," which means to raise some criticism of them in public: "I called him out for this bad attitude to work." These are just cultural idioms that happen to use this type of sentence construction.

Answer (score -2):

"To ask someone on a date" really means "To ask someone *who is on* on a date."
For example, "I'm sorry, I realize that you're in the middle of a date, but I'd really like to get your number..."

"To ask someone *out* on a date" is more correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).